# C# & Silverlight Basic Class Syntax with Get/Set Properties not working

Tags: c#, class, properties, get, set

I have a really, really simple class and I am tried to use the get/set properties but they just aren't working for me... I am sure it is the most obvious thing that I am over looking but I just can't see why they aren't working.  I have checked out the code that utilizes this class and its fine that I can see.

In the main code, if I type

```
Report r = new Report(); 
string str = "Taco";
r.displayName = str;
```

The report is declared alright and everything is set to empty strings or a new list or whatever the parameter's default is.  But every time I ran this the displayName always remained blank after the code finished executing...

so I tried putting a stop point in the Class displayName set property at set {_displayName = displayName;} and the value always passed in (displayName) was an empty string.... even though the string clearly says "Taco" in the main code.... I have no idea but I am sure its right in my face.  If you need more code I can provide it...

```
Report r = new Report(); 
string str = "Taco"; 
r.setReportDisplayName(str);
```

But for some reason the above works.

```
public class Report  
{
    private string _reportPath = string.Empty;
    public string reportPath
    {
        get { return _reportPath; }
        set { _reportPath = reportPath; }
    }

    private string _displayName = string.Empty;
    public string displayName
    {
        get { return _displayName; }
        set { _displayName = displayName; }
    }

    private List<parameter> _parameters = new List<parameter>();
    public List<parameter> parameters
    {
        get { return _parameters; }
        set { _parameters = parameters; }
    }

    public Report() { }
    public Report(string path, string display, List<parameter> param)
    {
        _reportPath = path;
        _displayName = display
        _parameters = param;
    }

    public void setReportDisplayName(string str)
    {
       _displayName = str; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining your properties incorrectly.  This should be done as:

```
private string _displayName = string.Empty;
public string displayName
{
    get { return _displayName; }
    set { _displayName = value; }
}
```

That being said, if you are using this for Silverlight, you most likely will want to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28VS.95%29.aspx).  Without this, data binding will not reflect changes made in code.

To implement this interface, you'll need to add this implementation.  A "standard" way to implement this is via:

```
public class Report : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Declare the PropertyChanged event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Raise the PropertyChanged event
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

At this point, you need to define your properties like:

```
private string _displayName = string.Empty;
public string DisplayName
{
    get { return _displayName; }
    set 
    { 
        if (_displayName != value)
        {
            _displayName = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DisplayName");
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this will allow you to data bind to your "Report" class.  You may also want to consider using [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of `List<T>` for any collections you want to use with data binding.

Comment: ohhh, how silly.  I kept comparing this code to stuff I had already written and things on the internet and now your code - I finally see what was out of place.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be assigning the value of the special variable **value** in your sets. **value** is what will be holding the (heh) value that was assigned to your property as it is passed into the set.

```
 public string reportPath
    {
        get { return _reportPath; }
        set { _reportPath = value; }
    }
```